# Compressing Kinect frame data

Tags: c#, sdk, kinect

I am using the Kinect 1.7 sdk and Im reading Color, Depth and Skeletal feeds.

At the moment when I process the data, its at around 30 frames per second.  When I save this data to disk a 30 second recording can be as large as 1 GB.

How can I compress the data when saving so that its a much more efficient size.  Should I pick out say 10 of the 30 frames per second?

Has anyone looked into something similar?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know the kinect gives you 2 images:
a bitmap from the VGA camera and a byte 2d array from the depth sensor.
Both can be compressed by compressing the VGA image to a JPG/PNG in color and compressing the depth image as a grayscale JPG/PNG...
That should save you quite a lot of space.

Comment: When I save the data to disk, I save the bytes of the color feed and the array of the depth data using a binarywriter.  Do you know how I'd approach saving this data compressed where its still useful?  In particular if I refer to the skeletal data.  It cant be converted into lossy image formats as the depth data can.  So my thoughts were to only read half the amount of frames produced per second and storing only half as this would still be useful joint movement information.

Comment: it would be better if you save the data as images in JPG/PNG. You will see significant decrease in size of your dataset. I have saved Depth and RGB images using OpenCV with OpenNI SDK. On average the size of one depth image is 90 kb and an RGB image is around 300 kb. I saved both of them in png format.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried this approach and it worked well.